# How to force OpensSSL to use SHA2 to generate random numbers?

Tags: random, openssl, cryptography

By default, OpenSSL uses the md_rand generator, which uses the MD5 hash as the pseudorandom function.

Knowing that OpenSSL PRNG options are : (see https://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/SecurityPolicy-2.0.pdf page 12)

- Hash
- HMAC
- CTR AES

How do I change that to one of the SHA2 family functions? or maybe HMAC?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to switch to HMAC, CTR or DUAL EC generator under OpenSSL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43453360/how-to-switch-to-hmac-ctr-or-dual-ec-generator-under-openssl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it is only possible to change how the openssl RNG works under FIPS mode.

Links that helped me :

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/22910/is-pseudo-random-generator-prg-in-openssl-uniformly-distributed

https://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/UserGuide-2.0.pdf